# Consultar registros en MySQL a partir del dia actual

Tags: mysql, date, select

Muy buenos días en mi base de datos tengo varios registros los campos importantes son fecha y hora, los cuales los estoy guardando de manera separada, necesito consultar estos registros a partir del día de hoy y hora 14:00:00 con esta consulta

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE fecha <= CURDATE() AND hora <= '14:00:00'
```

Me arroja los registros del día anterior pero excluyendo los que sean mayor de 14:00:00.
Podrían ayudarme por favor.
De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Necesitas los datos de hoy a partir de las 14 (o ea, las 14 en adelante) o los dias anteriores sin importar la hora y los de hoy _hasta_ las 14?

Comment: todos los registros a partir del día de hoy de las 14:00 hacia atrás

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto lo va a hacer:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla1
WHERE
    fecha < CURDATE()
    or hora <= '14:00:00'
```

Eso, asumiendo que no hay registros con `fecha` a futuro.... si los hubiera:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla1
WHERE
    fecha < CURDATE()
    or fecha = CURDATE()
        and hora <= '14:00:00'
```

Comment: Excelente, me ha ayudado mucho la primera, muchisimas gracias